# Trouble with NAT Type for 2 ps4's, Can't get open on both?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, playstation

I have had a PS4 since release and have never had much fault with it until Call of Duty Black Ops 3 came along. I was excited to play zombies again and couldn't wait to play with friends however I found I had a crappy NAT type. Cutting to the chase I forwarded my ports to static IP and hey presto I'm happy again. Some time has passed and Christmas has arrived and it seems I now have 2 Playstation 4's connected to my network, one mine and one my brother in law's.

One again cutting to the chase we cannot both have an open NAT type or even a Moderate NAT type simultaneously, it appears no matter how much I fiddle around with port forwarding, I am only able to get open for one ps4 and strict for the other. I have also tries getting rid of my opened ports and trying UPnP for both consoles but the same problem still persists. I have even heard of a programme that may use port forwarding for 2 static IP addresses, is this possible? Is there any way I can rectify this problem with or without the use of a programme that uses 2 static IP's for one port?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated as the problem is ongoing.
I have a virgin media VMDG480 router.

Comment: it is not possible to have two devices clambering for the same forwarded port or UPNP, unless very sophisticated load balancing techniques are used (its not simply a piece of software). The issue is, if someone remote wants to connect to a PS on your network on TCP\80, that can only happen if there is exactly ONE device listening on the inside of the NAT wall. you could get Two IPs from the ISP, and put one of the devices directly on-line (wired directly into the ISP network, not behind your router) so that they both have a unique Address/Port pairing.

Comment: Good god is it an irritating mechanic to find in some games. I've seen some outrageous blanketed port forwarding ranges including 443 & 80 which if some aren't aware are used for HTTPS/HTTP traffic so if you happen to be running a server there's a good chance you will simply never have NAT open. It's a terrible lazy net-code mechanic and it needs to stop. Properly setup online games should never require a client to have a bunch of ports forwarded. A few maybe but never ports that are commonly used for other things...

Answer (score 3):

UPnP is basically a way to set up some automated port forwarding.  The device that does the port forwarding needs to know what device the incoming traffic is meant for.  You can have that be one PS2, or another.

Your simple and easy solution is to use multiple public IPv4 addresses.  Contact your ISP to figure out what is needed to have a second static IPv4 address.  Note that I did not say "free".  Some ISPs (probably most of them) will restrict how many public IPv4 addresses you have.  Getting more than 1 may have a cost.

(You may also find that they don't provide you with 2.  You may have choices of 1, 5, 13, etc.  Why such odd-looking numbers?  This is because IPv4 tends to waste 2 addresses per subnetting block, and the ISP needs to use one of the addresses.  So, 4 - 3 = 1, 8-3 = 5, 16 - 3 = 13.  So there is a number that doubles, but also a subtraction of 3.  If you double up to 8 total, you end up with 5 usable.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm Having the exact same issue with trying to connect 2 PS4's on the same network. It's definitely NOT your router and is the limitation of the PS4 console. If you really enjoy gaming, my solution is to switch to PC or get an additional router and internet service.